# Why is my Array Modifier not curving my mesh like a square mesh?

Tags: modifiers, axis

I have done the procedure on YouTube about curving meshes with the axis,when I want to create an 8 pedal type of flower guard rotating on the y axis like the refrence photo my sword would create 3 extra meshes than when i try to rotate the mesh It creates a car tire like view turned at a certain angle

**Arrayed Mesh**

[image]

**Angled Car tire like Mesh**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the object that you are modifying with an array, and choosing Object | Apply | Rotation & Scale.  Whenever I have weird effects using an array modifier, it's usually (99% of the time) because I haven't applied the rotation and scale.

Comment: Sorry,was on a trip,It is rotating, but the three objects are still there,and the arraying effect is not working